# Strange behavior when masking a Leaflet map outside of a variety of separate polygons

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polygon, masking

Inspired by http://embed.plnkr.co/1I7dIw/, I'm trying to mask the remainder of the map outside of various polygons. But I'm encountering some challenges seemingly with the vertices. Could it be that some of the polygons are not closed so the masking is struggling with the start / stopping? Within each polygon the start / stop point is the same.

Or does the issue lie with the scripting, namely L.mask?

```
L.Mask = L.Polygon.extend({

    options: {
        stroke: false,
        color: '#333',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        clickable: true,
        outerBounds: new L.LatLngBounds([-90, -360], [90, 360])
    },

    initialize: function (latLngs, options) {    

         var outerBoundsLatLngs = [
            this.options.outerBounds.getSouthWest(),
            this.options.outerBounds.getNorthWest(),
            this.options.outerBounds.getNorthEast(),
            this.options.outerBounds.getSouthEast()
        ];

        L.Polygon.prototype.initialize.call(this, [outerBoundsLatLngs, latLngs], options);  
    }

});

L.mask = function (latLngs, options) {
    return new L.Mask(latLngs, options);
};
```

Looking for any help possible.

Demo ... https://jsfiddle.net/q7wo0ndf/7/ (apologies for being heavy-laden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `L.mask` Class is correct, you have a problem with your data.

Let leaflet work for you:

```
var sanbartolome_001 = ...;
var sanbartolome_002 = ...;
...

var options = {
    style: function(feature) {
        return {
            "color": "black",
            "weight": 3,
            "opacity": 1,
            "fillColor": "transparent",
            "fillOpacity": 0.0
        };
    }
};

var latLngs = [];

var rfc_nerfc_001 = new L.geoJson(sanbartolome_001.features, options).addTo(map);
var rfc_nerfc_002 = new L.geoJson(sanbartolome_002.features, options).addTo(map);
var rfc_nerfc_003 = new L.geoJson(sanbartolome_003.features, options).addTo(map);
var rfc_nerfc_004 = new L.geoJson(sanbartolome_004.features, options).addTo(map);
var rfc_nerfc_005 = new L.geoJson(sanbartolome_005.features, options).addTo(map);


latLngs.push(rfc_nerfc_001.getLayers()[0].getLatLngs());
latLngs.push(rfc_nerfc_002.getLayers()[0].getLatLngs());
latLngs.push(rfc_nerfc_003.getLayers()[0].getLatLngs());
latLngs.push(rfc_nerfc_004.getLayers()[0].getLatLngs());
latLngs.push(rfc_nerfc_005.getLayers()[0].getLatLngs());

var rfc_nerfc_000 = L.mask(latLngs).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Wow, seriously, thank you! That was way over my head. It's interesting how the order of operations was altered. So we generated the polygons then created the mask instead of vice versa it would seem? Then taking the ID of the layer and returning the array of points in the path we then pass that to L.mask? Does this just circumnavigate the errors with the data to create closed polygons that are then passed then effectively? Just trying to understand.

Again, thank you so much! 

Updated Fiddle ... https://jsfiddle.net/q7wo0ndf/8/

Comment: I don't understand your comment to 100% but I try to explain it. It's not complicate. The following replaces your loop to get the latlngs: with L.geojson we convert the geojson strings to leaflet layers, then we get the latlng from the only layer we have in the new geojsonLayer and add it to the latLngs array. We do this, because leaflet has the better logic to convert geojson to latlngs. And then we create L.mask with the array of latlngs same as before. Nothing with IDs ...

Comment: Copy that, I think I follow. Again, many thanks for your help on this!